# SSIS Conditional Split with 2 cases, case 2 should only run on case 1's successful completion

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS Data Flow Task with an OleDb Source, Conditional Split (w/ 2 cases), and 2 OleDb Destinations.

Like so...

```
                                                      ----------------------------
                                                +-->  | Case1: OleDb Destination |
----------------       ---------------------    |     ----------------------------
| OleDb Source |  -->  | Conditional Split |  --+
----------------       ---------------------    |     ----------------------------
                                                +-->  | Case2: OleDb Destination |
                                                      ----------------------------
```

What I want is to guarantee that Case2 ***only*** runs on the success of Case1. I know that without doing anything this is highly probable, but I just want to guarantee it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just connect Case1 to Case2 with an OnSuccess restriction keeping everything else the way it is now. That way, Case2 will only run if it is hit by the conditional split AND if Case1 gets run as well.

Comment: but the case1 goes into an oledb destination which has no success line.